# enhanced for loop with multidimensional array c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How would I use an enhanced for loop with a multidimensional array? (c++11, although feel free to answer for other versions)

We'll start with two dimensions...

```
int array[10][9];

//loop through first dimension (10)
    for(int i : sizeof(array)) {
       //do something
    }
```

Compiler error: this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found

Could it have something to do with a multidimensional array being really still 1 dimension? In other words, int array[10][9] is equivalent to int array[90]

Comment: Try 90 and try not being lazy

Comment: It's not laziness, it's more about the potential of the array changing sizes, minimizing the need to 'fix' additional code.

Comment: @cminusmius - Use iterators and STL. BTW That sentence is a contradiction

Comment: @ED Heal - Changing 1 line of code vs. x lines is smarter code.

Comment: Changing no lines of code is better still - See the answer below

Comment: I must be confused, but I think you would have to change 1 line of code if you wanted your array to be a different size.

Comment: Read about vectors - They grow and shrink at will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use range based loops, you should pass a container in which the `begin` and `end` has beed defined. Try this:

```
for(auto &rows: array) // rows
{
    for(auto &x: rows)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`int array[10][9]` is **not** equivalent to `int array[19]`, it can be defined as `int array[10*9]`.

Comment: Note that `&` in `auto & rows` is requirement, else the single-dimensional array will decay to pointer.